# Get back the touchpad scrolling missing in Kubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, touchpad, kubuntu, scrolling

How do I get back the touchpad scrolling in Kubuntu 10.04?

I upgraded my Gateway NV52 and can no longer scroll vertically with my touchpad. I'm really missing that feature since it helps to ease the RSI on my right index finger. How do I re-enable it?

After digging through menus, I found this in the touchpad settings dialog:

[image: touchpad settings dialog]

Changing it has no effect. Now what?

Comment: Install Synaptic?

Comment: My laptop is a Dell Studio 14. Though I run the modprobe command I am unable to activate the scrolling functionality for my touchpad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to be a general fault.  There are references to it way back before the final release.

Neither gpointings or gsynaptic work.

I also have that problem, with my Acer Aspire 5738.  As the OP says - frustrating and problematic in all sorts of ways.

**Update:**
Just found this, which works in Ubuntu.  Open a terminal, and type in the following lines:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

This enables scrolling for your current session - test and make sure it works.  If so, you can make it permanent by:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/options
```

and adding the line:

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```

Then close and reboot.

Comment: Excellent, that makes it work. Enjoy your rep...as soon as I can accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

An answer to another question provides an excellent introduction to [using *synclient* to tweak touchpad settings](https://superuser.com/questions/74024/two-finger-scrolling-with-ubuntu-9-10-samsung-nc10/114227#114227).  Obviously that answer doesn't provide you with the correct settings to accomplish your goal, but it should give you an idea of where to look.

Kubuntu should install the [*xserver-xorg-input-synaptics*](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics) package which includes the [Synaptics touchpad driver](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man4/synaptics.4.html) and the associated [*synclient* utility](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/synclient.1.html).  See their respective manpages (linked) for details.  If you don't already have *synclient* on your system, install the above package to get it.

*This post is Community Wiki so others can fill in specifics of how to use synclient to solve this particular problem.*